# After taking picture how to set that picture in the layout in Sencha Touch?

Tags: camera, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to take a picture using camera API and display this in the screen. I am able to take the picture. But not getting how to display it in my screen. For this i wrote the below code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.CameraPanel', {    extend: 'Ext.Panel',


config: {
    ui: 'light',
    layout: {
        type: 'card'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            handler: function(button, event) {
                Ext.device.Camera.capture({
                    source: 'camera',
                    destination: 'data',


                    success: function(image) {


                        takenimage.setSrc(image);
                    },


                    failure: function() {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'There was an error when acquiring the picture.');
                    },
                    scope: this
                });
            },
            height: 33,
            left: 60,
            top: 400,
            ui: 'decline-round',
            width: 200,
            text: 'Take a Photo'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'image',
            itemId: 'takenimage',
            src: 'image'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

I am new to this sencha platform. Please help.

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using html tag, i am able to fix this issue..